# $.map and $.grep together?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this simple script:

```
var stdout = "A test.js\nD README.md\nD CONTRIBUTING.md\nM something.txt";

var out = $.grep( stdout.split("\n"), function (row) {
    return (row.substring(0, 1) == "D");
});
```

[JSFIddle [**x**]](http://jsfiddle.net/DVL2H/)

It returns an array with only the rows starting with `D`, this is the result:

```
D README.md
D CONTRIBUTING.md
```

I need to get, instead, an array with the rows starting with `D` but I need to strip the `D`  from the rows, so I would need this result:

```
README.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
```

If I use only `$.map` I can't find a way to don't return anything in case the condition is not fulfilled...

```
var out = stdout.split("\n").map(function (row) {
    return (row.substring(0, 1) == "D") ? row.substring(1).trim() : null;
});
// returns: [null, 'README.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', null]
// I need: ['README.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md']
```

I think I should use a mix of `$.map` and `$.grep` but looks like too much code for this simple task.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) - if you return `undefined` from $.map() callback, that value will be ignored

```
var regex = /^D/;
var out = $.map(stdout.split("\n"), function (row) {
    return regex.test(row) ? $.trim(row.substring(1)) : undefined
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EMU62/)